# Basic calculator will only add values

Tags: python

I'm new to python and am trying to make a basic calculator that takes two numbers and performs the operation specified by the user, but regardless of the operation I enter, the numbers always add.

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number. "))
print(" ")
num2 = int(input("Enter another number. "))
print(" ")
operation = input("Type Add, Subtract, Multiply, or Divide" )

if operation == "Add" or "add":
    add = num1 + num2
    print(add)
elif operation == "Subtract" or "subtract":
    sub = num1 - num2
    print(sub)
elif operation == "Multiply" or "multiply":
    mult = num1 * num2
    print(mult)
elif operation == "Divide" or "divide":
    div = num1 / num2
    print(div)
else:
    print("Enter a valid operation: ")
```

With what I have, if num1 = 10 and num2 = 5 and I enter "multiply" the result I get is 15, not 50.

Comment: `operation == "Add" or "add"` should be `operation == "Add" or operation == "add"`

Comment: `if operation in ["add", "Add"]`

Comment: Or `operation = input("Type Add, Subtract, Multiply, or Divide" ).lower()` followed by the *single* checks like `if operation == "add"` - this will handle *any* amount of case mixing.

Answer (score 1):

```py
if operation == "Add" or "add"
```

These are two conditions:

1. `if operation == "Add"` which does what you expect.
2. `if "add"` - Always evaluates to `True` because it's a constant string.
   So you could just as well have written:
   `if True`. You need to replace it with:

```py
if operation == "Add" or operation == "add"
```

Anyway, I would like to suggest a few things.

#### Lowercase then check only once

You should lowercase your input string instead of double checking "Add" or "add":

```py
num1 = int(input("Enter a number. "))
print(" ")
num2 = int(input("Enter another number. "))
print(" ")
operation = input("Type Add, Subtract, Multiply, or Divide" ).lower()  # Notice the `lower` here

if operation == "add":
    add = num1 + num2
    print(add)
elif operation == "subtract":
    sub = num1 - num2
    print(sub)
elif operation "multiply":
    mult = num1 * num2
    print(mult)
elif operation "divide":
    div = num1 / num2
    print(div)
else:
    print("Enter a valid operation: ")
```

#### Use the built-in [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module

The `operator` module contains exactly the methods that you seek for. You could use it for convenience (haven't tested, should work):

```py
import operator
keywords = {"add": "add", "subtract": "sub", "multiply": "mul", "divide": "truediv"}

num1 = int(input("Enter a number. "))
print(" ")
num2 = int(input("Enter another number. "))
print(" ")
operation = input("Type Add, Subtract, Multiply, or Divide" )
op_func = keywords.get(operation.lower(), "add")  # defaults to add
print(getattr(operator, op_func)(num1, num2))
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fun(operation, num1,num2):
    operation = operation.lower()

    if operation == "add":
        add = num1 + num2
        print(add)
    elif operation == "subtract":
        sub = num1 - num2
        print(sub)
    elif operation == "multiply":
        mult = num1 * num2
        print(mult)
    elif operation == "divide":
        div = num1 / num2
        print(div)
    else:
        print("Enter a valid operation: ")

fun('multiply', 10,5)
```

**Why:**
`if operation == "add" or "Add":`  this is always `True`
We can use `if operation == "add" or operation == "Add":`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number. ")) 
print(" ") 
num2 = int(input("Enter another number. ")) 
print(" ") 
operation = str(input("Type Add, Subtract, Multiply, or Divide" ))
if operation == "Add" or operation =="add": 
    add = num1 + num2 
    print(add) 
elif operation == "Subtract" or operation =="subtract": 
    sub = num1 - num2 
    print(sub) 
elif operation == "Multiply" or operation =="multiply":
    mult = num1 * num2 
    print(mult) 
elif operation == "Divide" or operation =="divide": 
    div = num1 / num2 
    print(div) 
else: 
    print("Enter a valid operation: ")
```

Because of **or** operation with string, all your conditions will be true.
That's why it will only go to first condition no matter what you give in the input.